# If Statment in a Loop Blade Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to run condition a loop inside of larvel with blade with no luck. I can get the individual items out fine by {{$this->active}} but I want to check a value inside a loop.

Hope this makes sense.

```
   @foreach ($clients as $client)

       @if($client->active == 0){
           <a href="{{ URL::route('published', $client->id) }}/1">Published</a>
       @endif
       @if($client->active == 1){
          <a href="{{ URL::route('published', $client->id) }}/0">Unpublished</a>
       @endif

   @endforeach
```

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but try `@foreach($clients as $client)` (without the space), and `@if($client->active == 0)` without the { at the end.

Comment: Posted it as the answer, so you can accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try @foreach($clients as $client) (without the space), and @if($client->active == 0) without the { at the end.

```
@foreach($clients as $client)
    @if($client->active == 0)
        <a href="{{ URL::route('published', $client->id) }}/1">Published</a>
    @endif
    @if($client->active == 1)
        <a href="{{ URL::route('published', $client->id) }}/0">Unpublished</a>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

(Posted as comment, but is the answer)